# How to change node languages in batches?

Tags: drupal

If I'm doing content translation in Drupal 6, how do I change the language on a large amount of nodes without having to do it for each node? I have over 500 nodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Views bulk operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) a module for views would be one option. Another would be SQL. I would prefer vbo but am not sure if there is an change language action for it.

Comment: But If I'm not wrong, the VBO only updates the language field in the database table node. In my drupal installation the node custom fields also have a language attribute on its table.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was looking for. There's a module called [Language Assignment](http://drupal.org/project/languageassign).

Comment: Language Assignment is no longer mantained and it has a critical bug that can lead to data loss

Comment: Thanks for the warning. Is there an alternative you would recommend at this point?