# How to change entity language in bulk?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a site in drupal which is in spanish by default. Now I want to add the english translation. It has a lot of entities "producto" with undefined ('und') language. I want to mass assign the 'es' language to them. Before posting this question I have checked this other question [How to change node languages in batches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757450/how-to-change-node-languages-in-batches) but I'm unable to accomplish what I want. Let me explain:

a) I have tried Language Assignement but it last commit was 1 year ago and it has a critical bug that can lead to data loss (I reproduced the error too) I also tried with the patch from user barami but the data loss persists.

b) View Bulk Operations: I've tried it, but it does only update the field in database table "node". Not the other ones.

c) So I checked out how the drupal database works and created a sql script which also leads to data loss:

```
-- Step 1 Node lang
update node set language='es' where type='producto';

-- Step 2 body field
update field_data_body set language='es' where bundle='producto';

-- Step 3 Field comment vody
update field_data_comment_body set language='es' where bundle='comment_node_producto';

-- Step 4 For each field of producto, update language
update field_data_field_precio set language='es' where bundle='producto';
update field_revision_field_precio set language='es' where bundle='producto';

(...)
```

I have the following translation modules activated:
Internationalization, Block languages, Field translation, Menu translation, Multilingual content, Multilingual select, Synchronize translations, Taxonomy translation, Translation redirect, Translation sets

What Am I doing wrong with my sql script? Are there other plugins to accomplish what I want to do? Any suggestion will be appreciated Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I bulk set the language on my site:

1. Using Views Bulk Optimization, select all nodes you want to change, use the 'Change value' option and then change the value to language you want.
2. After you've done this, the field values will not appear when editing the nodes, so you need to run a script, e.g. `UPDATE database.field_data_body SET language='en' WHERE bundle='page'` (use your db name, field name, and bundle as appropriate).

IMPORTANT: If you have any custom url aliases, they will be overwritten with this approach, due to a problem with pathauto, but there's a work-around: first go to /admin/config/search/path/settings, and change the 'Update action' option to 'Do nothing. Leave the old alias intact.', then change this value back once you've run your Views Bulk Operations action.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I want to remark I found out that fields language must remain 'und' in order for Drupal to work properly (including fields appearing when editing nodes)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can make a view listing your entities, you can use the Views Bulk Operations module to do this.  [I just explained how to do this the other day for nodes on Drupal Answers.](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/55296/5147)

Comment: Are you sure this procedure is 100% safe? Someone recommended me that the nodes marked as 'und' language should remain intact to avoid data loss. So he recommended me to copy nodes and mark the new copies as 'es' but he didn't tell me how to do it.

Comment: Appart from that, if I'm not wrong, this procedure only affects the database table node, not the other ones.

Comment: @Roger Yes, this procedure is safe, but you should always make a backup first before doing a major operation like this.  I don't think you need to duplicate the data; if it were me, I would change the language directly as described in my answer above.  But, this depends on the default language of your site and how you have configured entity translation.

Comment: With a clean installation of Drupal with just a few modules including Views, VBO, ... the field language is available in the multiselect under "Modify Entity Values" But with the drupal which I want to translate, the option is not available. I think that the option may be removed by another active module to avoid data loss

Comment: I tried this, and VBO does permit the default language to be set. However, all the field values are lost, so doing something like a bulk export won't work, and it will appears as though all content has been lost. The content does appear, but only after viewing the languages list, and then returning to the form, which must cause Entity Translation to perform clean-up function. In other words, this doesn't work in practice.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution would be to just execute the first SQL because I have discovered that the fields language must remain 'und'.

```
update node set language='es' where type='producto';
```

Comment: This does not account for revisions or fields.